# Write class objects from a running jar file to a file in another directory

Tags: java, serialization, executable-jar, serializable, file-writing

Basically my program reads parameters from a class object in a memory-file at startup and if parameters are changed in the running program it overwrites memory-file and reads from it again to update parameters.

My application works as should in the IDE.
Then I built my first jar from my IDE and ran it from a batch-file and it works, but not as expected.

If the memory-file exists it is reed at program startup without problem.

But when I try to change program parameters or start program without memory-file and it is supposed to overwrite the memory-file with updated class object alt. create a new, it returns "FileNotFoundException".

Here is my amateur code, I created a class with the purpose of writing/reading a "SaveClass" object to/from a text file:

```java
public class ManageMemory {
    //filepath
    private String MEMORY_DIR = new StringBuffer(System.getProperty("user.home"))
            .append("\\Documents\\memory.txt").toString();
    private File targetFile = new File (MEMORY_DIR);

    //writes selected object to txt-file" with exceptions included
    public void writeToMemory(SaveClass object) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(MEMORY_DIR);
            ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
            //write object to file
            o.writeObject(object);

            o.close();
            f.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found while writing");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error initializing stream");
        }
    }

    //reads current object in memory directory
    public SaveClass readFromMemory() {
        SaveClass inMemory = new SaveClass();
        if (!targetFile.exists()) {
            writeToMemory(inMemory);
        }
        try {
            FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(MEMORY_DIR);
            ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(f);

            inMemory = (SaveClass) o.readObject();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found while reading");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error initializing stream");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return inMemory;
    }
}
```

I have searched for information about how to approach my problem, but not found much I understand.
I tested to print the canWrite() on my save file while running the .jar program and it returned true.

Comment: Perhaps if you printed out the value of 'MEMORY_DIR' and then tried accessing  that value if might give you a clue as to  which file your programming is attempting to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to find out what’s really happening is with these steps:

- Replace all usage of java.io.File with the newer [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html) class.
- Replace all usage of FileOutputStream with [Files.newOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#newOutputStream(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.OpenOption...)).
- Make sure every single `catch` block prints a stack trace.

java.io.File is a very old class.  It has a number of design flaws, simply because API design wasn’t as well understood in 1995.

But the [java.nio.file](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) package is more modern and corrects all of those problems.  It also has much more detailed and informative exceptions.

Using that package looks very similar:

```
public void writeToMemory(SaveClass object) {
    try (ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(
        Files.newOutputStream(
            Paths.get(MEMORY_DIR)))) {

        //write object to file
        o.writeObject(object);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error initializing stream");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This will print an exception that explains exactly why the file cannot be written.

(Notice that I am using a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement—that is, the ObjectOutputStream creation is inside parentheses right after `try`—which will automatically close the ObjectOutputStream, which in turn will close the underlying OutputStream.)

Comment: There is so much to learn, anyway I did as you told me and guess what, it worked except it was a access denied error when writing so I changed location to my other hard-drive for testing and it worked. Somehow I could not write to documents folder. Thanks a lot! Would upvote if I could :)